# Perl: Iterating over hash does not work with nested grep in while condition

Tags: perl, while-loop, grep

I'm facing an issue related to while condition.
My simple hash:

```
my %ConnectionsIP = (
                '10.130.20.21' => 0,
                '10.130.20.22' => 0,
                '10.130.20.23' => 0,
                '10.130.20.24' => 0
            );
```

The code below works for me as I expected.

```
my $i = 0;
while (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '0' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
    while ((my $key, my $value) = each (%ConnectionsIP)){
         print "KEY: $key, VAL: $value\n";
         $ConnectionsIP{$key} = $i++;
         next;
    }
}
```

Each pair (key, value) is displaying properly during executing. The problem is the next grep inside second while condition:

```
my $i = 0;
while (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '0' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
    while ((my $key, my $value) = each (%ConnectionsIP)){
         print "KEY: $key, VAL: $value\n";
         $ConnectionsIP{$key} = $i++;

         if (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '1' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
             print "I have 1!\n";
             sleep 10;
         }
         next;
    }
}
```

During executing the second code still is printing the same key with increasing value. What is the reason of this? Thanks for each feedback and solutions :)

Comment: Can you state what the code wants to accomplish?  (Increment all 0 values, and print when it's 1 ... ?)

Comment: It is short version of my code presented only to reproduce my problem. I would like to get the same result as first one but display when value 1 exist.  I'm surprised that iteration in second code does not work as I expected (similarly as 1 code)

Comment: These overlaying `while`s where you poke at the hash's iterator just ask for trouble; your first sample works just barely. See @schwern's answer.  If you want to do more inside the inner loop I'd strongly recommend to rewrite that.  But I don't see what you want, since the output of the first code is mysterious to me. So: can you state in words the purpose of the code?

Comment: Tip: That `next` is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`each`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) is fraught with peril. Every hash has its own iterator. It uses this for things like `each`, `keys`, and `values`.

`each(%ConnectionsIP)` iterates its way through each pair in `%ConnectionsIP` returning one key/value pair at a time. It uses `%ConnectionsIP`'s iterator to remember where it is.

`keys %ConnectionsIP` iterates through all the keys of `%ConnectionsIP` returning them all as an array. In doing so ***it resets the iterator***.

> Each hash or array has its own internal iterator, accessed by each, keys, and values. The iterator is implicitly reset when each has reached the end as just described; it can be explicitly reset by calling keys or values on the hash or array. If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, the effect on the iterator is unspecified;

```
my $i = 0;
while (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '0' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
    while ((my $key, my $value) = each (%ConnectionsIP)){
         print "KEY: $key, VAL: $value\n";
         $ConnectionsIP{$key} = $i++;
         next;
    }
}
```

This is safe because you call `keys`, resetting the iterator. And then do a complete iteration with `each`. The call to `keys` does not interfere with the call to `each`.

```
my $i = 0;
while (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '0' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
    while ((my $key, my $value) = each (%ConnectionsIP)){
         print "KEY: $key, VAL: $value\n";
         $ConnectionsIP{$key} = $i++;

         if (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '1' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
             print "I have 1!\n";
             sleep 10;
         }
         next;
    }
}
```

This is not safe. While `each` is iterating through `%ConnectionsIP` you're calling `keys %ConnectionsIP` resetting `each`'s iterator.

Rule of thumb: don't mix `keys` and `values` with `each`.

---

There's a couple ways to fix this. You could use [Hash::StoredIterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::StoredIterator) which lets you independently iterate over a hash.

```
use Hash::StoredIterator qw{
    iterator
};

my $i = 0;
while (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '0' } keys %ConnectionsIP) {
    # Create an iterator independent of the shared one in %ConnectionsIP
    my $connections_iter = iterator %ConnectionsIP;
    while (my($key, $value) = $connections_iter->()){
         print "KEY: $key, VAL: $value\n";
         $ConnectionsIP{$key} = $i++;

         if (grep { $ConnectionsIP{$_} eq '1' } keys %ConnectionsIP){
             print "I have 1!\n";
         }
         next;
    }
}
```

Or, and this is better, you can rework your code to not do so many loops within loops within loops. Your code will take `n^3` to run, meaning as the number of keys in `%ConnectionsIP` increases the time will be cubed. 3 takes 27. 4 takes 64. 5 takes 125.

Fortunately your code looks like it's just some code to test out this behavior.